# Using a predefined struct in an enum

Tags: rust

I saw this code:

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}

fn main() {}
```

It looks like the author of the code defines structs right inside the enum. What's the correct term for this? How does this work? Is there a way to put a predefined struct inside an enum?

```rust
struct Run { distance: i32 }
enum Message {
    Run, // already defined so we just write Run instead of Run { distance: i32 }
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}

fn main() {}
```

I guess this will **not** work, so what should I do instead?

Comment: Read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html).

Answer (score 3):

The enum members you are defining and the struct or value they contain are distinct, so you can't *quite* do what you're trying to do; but you can come close:

```
struct Run { distance: i32 }
enum Message {
    Run(Run),
    Quit,
}

fn main() {
    let m = Message::Run(Run { distance: 32 });
}
```

In this case you have a `struct Run` as well as a `Message::Run` which contains a single value that happens to be a `struct Run`.

Comment: Message::Run instead of Run::Message, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Enum variants can store data in rust. This is often referred to as a sum type or an algabreic data type.

That data can be a struct or a tuple (which is basically just a simple form of struct), and it's type is `Enum::Variant`.

In your second example, the type Message::Run is distinct from the Run type at the crate root, so rustc would not use crate::Run as the type for Message::Run. To do this correctly, you could either declare Run in line as in your first example or make your variant `Run(Run)`.